# Pulling Data from Multiple Tables to one Form with a Junction Table

Tags: c#, sql

Using C#/Visual Studio 2013 connecting to a DB on MSSQL Server 2014
I would like to pull data from multiple tables to one form.
Form1(datagridview) > Form2 (txtboxes; connected to other tables)

This is my code from Form1>Form2

```
private void cLMASTERDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
        MedicalSystemDataSet.CLMASTERRow SelectedRow;

        SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)cLMASTERBindingSource.Current;
        SelectedRow = (MedicalSystemDataSet.CLMASTERRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

        frmDetail PatientDetail = new frmDetail();
        PatientDetail.LoadPersonal(SelectedRow.ACCOUNT);
        PatientDetail.Show();
    }'
```

This is my code from Form2:

```
internal void LoadPersonal(String ACCOUNT)
    {
        cLMASTERTableAdapter.FillByACCOUNT(medicalSystemDataSet.CLMASTER, ACCOUNT);
    }'
```

My WHERE SQL Query for FillByACCOUNT is as

```
WHERE ACCOUNT = @ACCOUNT
```

With the above code Form2 loads with data from the cLMASTER Table but not the other tables.

My SQL Query for pull data from the other tables is:

```
SELECT c.ACCOUNT, c.FAMILY, c.DOCTOR, c.PLNAME, c.PFNAME, p.Account, p.PA_PatientID, w.PA_PatientID, w.Code_OD1, w.Rx_OD1
FROM CLMASTER AS c INNER JOIN
 PA_Account AS p ON c.ACCOUNT = p.Account INNER JOIN
 CL_Wear2 AS w ON p.PA_PatientID = w.PA_PatientID
WHERE (c.ACCOUNT = @ACCOUNT)'
```

When I run the above in SQL Query Builder and execute, I enter the account number I want and the query is able pull data from the other tables.  However, I get an error when I run the application by that query.  Errors out with an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.ConstraintException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are way out of your depth.  I would suggest you start with the basics, because you're only going to run into more and more complications.  Fundamentals of C#, ADO.NET, WinForms, SQL and maybe LINQ.  Here's what you're trying to achieve: A DoubleClick EVENT should get the PersonID of the record that was clicked and pass it as a parameter to the form you're opening.  That form then should use it to filter it's other 3 tables.

Comment: So what's your problem? And, BTW, which database are you using? DB2?

Comment: Use lightswitch, it will make life a lot easier for you.

Comment: @Kris: Yep, i'm way out of my depth... but any help would be greatly appreciated.  Would love to learn the fundamentals but just need a quick and dirty app up and running before the 30th. :)

Comment: For quick and dirty i suggest you outsource it :)

Comment: @MikeMiller: I strongly agree.  However a certain level of understanding is still required if you plan on doing anything useful.  (JavaScript, jQuery, jQueryMobile, HTML, CSS, Entity Framework, Lightswitch's JavaScript implementation of EF... maybe WebApi and C# too.)

Comment: @Kris: Still would like to know what's is going on... for future reference.  Are you for hire for help? :)

Comment: I am able to get the doubleclick event to load the data into form2, but i'm unable to get the data from the other tables to load into form2.  i'm created a sql query that was able to do it though... but am getting an error when trying to load the form by that query.